# R optim() L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Tags: r, gamma-distribution, fitdistrplus

I am using MLE and l-moments method for gamma distribution, exponential distribution and weibull distribution.

I used fitdistr() in gamma distribution.

I have an error messga saying that  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
And I wonder if I can fix this by change the optimization method from L-BFGS-B to BFGS.

> Error in stats::optim(x = c(36.576, 1.778, 30.48, 1.524, 21.336, 3.302,  : 
>     L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

Here's my code.

```
# Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE)
  gams_mle <- fitdistr(month_temp, "gamma",  list(shape = s_gam, rate = 1/g_gam), lower = c(0,0))
  gam_mle <- c(as.numeric(gams_mle$estimate[1]), as.numeric(gams_mle$estimate[2]))
```

Sample data:

0   1972    4   4   4.318   2

1   1972    4   4   6.604   4

2   1972    4   4   3.302   6

3   1972    4   4   0.762   8

4   1972    5   5   0.254   10

5   1972    5   5   3.048   12

6   1972    5   5   0.254   14

7   1972    5   5   1.778   16

8   1972    5   5   0.254   18

9   1972    5   5   1.778   20

10  1972    5   5   0.762   22

and in my main file, see the code below:

```
# 2. Gamma distribution function (alpha, beta)
j = 13
for (i in 1:12){
  month_temp = input_data[,3]
  index = month_temp == i
  month_temp = input_data[index,5] 

  par_gam = gamma_fit(month_temp, option = FALSE)
  par_matrix[j,1] = i
  par_matrix[j,2] = 2
  par_matrix[j, 3:4] = par_gam[1:2]
  par_matrix[j, 8:9] = par_gam[3:4]
  j = j + 1     
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide data so that we can reproduce the error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For code debugging please always ask with a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) example per the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [`r`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) tag description, with the desired output.

Comment: @Lyngbakr I provided partial data and I am not sure if its enough to reproduce the error.